# SAP Crystal Report If Then Else Statement Color Highlighting

Tags: if-statement, crystal-reports

So I have zero knowledge of how to operate SAP Crystal Reports but find myself needing to make a report for some everyday tasks. I found a similar report already created in the system and tried adapting it (after "saving as" so I don't break the original file) but am not getting the results I am looking for.

My goal is to highlight specific information when it appears. If a person makes a mistake and enters the wrong information in our software, the report will highlight the error for me.

All I would like it to do is when there is information that doesn't match the formula it will highlight it yellow or red etc.

For example, code I've been trying to get work is:

```
if ({vw_Tickets.SiteName} = "SCALE" and {vw_Tickets_Material_Detail.MaterialCode} = "22CD") then crred else crwhite;
```

I have different variations of the above code stacked on top of one another, the names change but that's about it.

I don't know if I'm using the formula wrong or if I'm typing it in the wrong location. To make my changes I'm in Section Expert > Details > Color > and then the red x-2 next to the color list > details > background color.

The Highlighting Expert doesn't do what I need it to do. I need it to highlight when something unusual happens.

I know that probably doesn't make a lot of sense, but any help or direction would be appreciated!

[Screenshot of crystal report formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdZi9.png)

Comment: From your screenshot it seems that there are some "else"s missing in it: There can be exactly one result of a formula, therefore I would expect CR to evaluate all "if"s, but to fill only the last "if"'s result into the formula result.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolons are not correct. The formula should only have one result. Try to write something like this:

```
If {siteName} = "TIGER-TECH" Then crlime Else
If {siteName} = "EMPLOYEE DUMP ACCOUNT" Then crlime Else
If {siteName} = "SCALE CACHE" ... Then crRed
// Last One
Else "crWhite"
```

If you want to leave the original font color you should use "crNoColor".